# Help to understand this sample sentence in the Oxford dictionary

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> ‘That was until we discovered congee, the soupy rice porridge which is to East and Southeast Asia what oatmeal is to Scotland.’

While I was going through the examples for the word [Congee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/congee) in the Oxford dictionary, I bumped into the sentence. I am not sure how I should understand or parse the sentence to make it grammatically correct? And what is the sentence trying to tell us?

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct. It is about porridge, which in Southeast Asia is made from rice, and in Scotland is made from oatmeal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is setting up an analogy, and **what** is a placeholder for the relationship of the food to the place:

A is to B as C is to D
A : B :: C : D

congee (the soupy rice porridge) : East/Southeast Asia :: oatmeal : Scotland

[The role congee plays] in the East/Southeast is what [i.e. the role oatmeal plays] in Scotland.

> The horse-drawn cart was to the 19th century what the truck was to the
>   20th, *a vehicle to haul goods and produce*.

If the sentence above had stopped at "20th." then **what** would refer to an unspoken, implicit idea, which we could make concrete: "a vehicle to haul goods and produce". When the relationship is not made explicit, there is only a blank, **what**.

Congee, the soupy rice porridge is to East and Southeast Asia *what* oatmeal is to Scotland, *a staple food*.

Comment: Can we just use *as*, instead of *what* for this kind of analogy? Or both *as* and *what* are interchangeable for this usage?

Comment: Without the placeholder, **what**, the listener expects the speaker to say what the two have in common. *Baseball in America **is** as cricket **is** in England.*  That's grammatical and expresses a *similarity*. The similarity could be "they are both televised", "they are both dwindling in popularity", "they are both becoming more popular", whatever. On the other hand, with a placeholder, *Baseball in America is what cricket is in England*, the listener would assume the speaker means they have an analogous role in their respective contexts. The listener isn't waiting for anything more.

Answer (score 2):

> That was until we discovered *congee*, [the soupy rice porridge] which **is to** East and Southeast Asia **what oatmeal is to** Scotland.’

When we have to explain something unfamiliar to the layperson we can use the following type of construction, [term] + is to [Z]  what [nearest equivalent] to [A]

> *Polenta* **is to** Italians **what**  cornmeal **is to** Americans
>   *Akvavit* **is to** Sweden **what**  vodka **is to** Poland and Russia

Comment: As I asked in the other answer: Can we just use *as*, instead of *what* for this kind of analogy? Or both *as* and *what* are interchangeable for this usage? thanks!